# Can I use a siemens type qaf2 breaker to replace a siemens type mp-at breaker?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, circuit

can I replace a siemens 15 amp type MP-AT breaker with a 15 amp siemens type QAF2 breaker

Comment: Your panel should have a label on it saying what breaker types are allowed.

Comment: If it isn't on that list, it's a bad idea even if it seems to fit.

Comment: @keshlam That's not fully accurate.  Siemens has a long list of compatible breakers for old panels.

Comment: ... Granted, @RobertChapin

Comment: Can you post a picture of the label on the inside of your panel's door please?

Comment: The model number of your panel might help also, if labels are missing.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you may replace an MP* breaker with a Q* (assuming the panel allowed the MP in the first place, of course).

Siemens has fully discontinued the “Murray” name that they acquired years ago and issued a letter showing the UL-listed Q* types that replace the old MP* types:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/dcc-data-extract/new-delta/asset/Compas/daily/Compas/Marketing%20Flyer/MurraySubstitutionLetter.pdf?151123

If you really mean a plain MP-AT breaker (and not an MP-AT2), it will depend on the specific setup. The MP-AT is a two-pole breaker, meaning it can support 240V loads and multi-wire branch circuits. These cannot be replaced with a QAF2, because the QAF2 is a tandem breaker and attaches to only one pole. This means that either the load won't work (if it expects 240V on the two terminals and instead sees 0V) or in the MWBC case could end up putting up to 30A of current on the neutral wire (instead of at most 15A) and possibly cause a fire.

The equivalent of the two-pole Murray type MP-AT is Siemens type QAF.